# How to get item details from a transaction netsuite freemarker advanced pdf/html

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I am working on a salesOrder template, I need to put some informations from the items.
I am able to print the item field values, but it prints the values of the first line only and it is repeated for all the lines.
itemid is correctly updated for each line, but itemimage is not

Any idea?

```
            <#if record.item?has_content>
                <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
                <!-- start lines -->
                <#list record.item as line>
                 <#if line_index==0>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="5"></th>
                      <th colspan="8">Commercial Reference</th>
                      <th colspan="11">${line.description@label}</th>
                      <th colspan="2" align="center">Size</th>
                      <th align="center" colspan="3">${line.quantity@label}</th>
                      <th align="right" colspan="4">${line.rate@label}</th>
                      <th align="right" colspan="4">${line.amount@label}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  </#if>
                 <tr>
                    <#assign itemid = record.item.item>
                      <#assign itemimage = record.item.item.custitem_atlas_item_image>
                        <td colspan="5" align="center">--${itemid}-${itemimage}-${line.item}<@filecabinet nstype="image" alt="" src="${itemimage}" style="float: left; width: 50px; height:100px" /></td>
                        <td colspan="8"><span class="itemname">${line.custcol_noda_style}</span></td>
                        <td colspan="11">${line.custcol_noda_description}</td>

                      <td colspan="2">${line.custcol_noda_size}</td>
                      <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${line.quantity}</td>
                      <td align="right" colspan="4">${line.rate}</td>
                      <td align="right" colspan="4">${line.amount}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </#list><!-- end lines --></table>

                  <hr /></#if>
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but `record.item` should stay the same, and what changes is `line`. So shouldn't `record.item.item` be replaced with `line.<something>`?

Answer (score 1):

Reply from the netsuite support:

> The syntax to print values from item record on transaction via {item.item.fieldid} might not work this is a current limitation for the item join on Advanced PDF. It will only render the value used for the first line item only. An enhancement request was filed to further improve this.
> This is documented on SuiteAnswers ID: 84605.

Answer (score 0):

These:

```
<#assign itemid = record.item.item>
<#assign itemimage = record.item.item.custitem_atlas_item_image>
```

should be:

```
<#assign itemid = line.item>
<#assign itemimage = line.item.custitem_atlas_item_image>
```

Comment: Hello @bknights, same behaviour